# How to export only the Client to a jar from a RMI - Eclipse

Tags: java, jar, export, rmi

I have created for a first time a programm in Java SWING including RMI Connection with PORT (Server - Client) in Eclipse.

Now I want to export only the Client (to a jar File if its possible ) and test it (via install it) to another computer so I could see if it works and how it works.

The Structure of my project in Eclipse is like :

[image: Client]

From there I want only the Client to export and install it to another PC and start the Programm with the LoginForm.java. The .jar export files that have tryed and created they dont do nothing at all. Also dont know if I have to do something specific with the Build Path or the folders (like Image folder) that I have extra create.

Comment: Make sure you're exporting it as a `Runnable Jar`. Eclipse should have a fairly simple export wizard that gives you some options on how you want handle the libraries. Maybe [this eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-export-runnable-jar.htm) can help you.

Comment: Hava try it and nowthing happens when I double cliked it

Answer (score 1):

*JavaMunich:*

> Hava try it and nowthing happens when I double cliked it

---

You can't just double click a `.jar` file, you can execute the program by using the following command.

```
java -jar YOURJAR.jar
```

You could make a .bat file with the command in it to make it easier for future executions.

1. Open notepad.
2. write :- `java -jar YOURJAR.jar.`
3. Save it with the extension .bat.
4. copy it to the directory which has the .jar file.
5. double click it to run your jar file.

Comment: thank you very much I wouild do it ....but how I package the client and how the server ?